# Rails 3.1 Dropdown menu and multiple datas

Tags: ruby-on-rails

it's possible make a dropdown menu where menu's fields are datas that comes from several mysql tables? I explain better: suppose that I've two models "Hardwares" and "Brands" and suppose that:

```
class Hardware < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :brand
end
```

and

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :hardwares
end
```

and suppose that Hardware migration is:

```
class Hardwares < ActiveRecord::Migration

def self.up
  create_table "hardwares" do |t|
    t.column "model", :string
    t.column "id", :integer
     t.column "brand_id", :integer
  end
end

def self.down
  drop_table "hardwares"
end
```

I'd want that each dropdown menu element is something like that:

```
@hw=Hardwares.find(params[:id])

[@hw.brand.name,@hw.model]   <- Dropdown menu's element
```

In witch way can I do this?
Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to associate Hardware to a Project but when listing the Hardware you want to include the brand name to avoid a list of model numbers.

**Update**: Define the following in your Hardware model:

```
def model_with_brand_name
  "#{self.brand.name} #{self.model}"
end
```

Unfortunately, the Rails API docs don't allow linking directly to methods but what you want is collection_select.

In a form, you can create a select element menu using the following method:

```
<%= collection_select :project_id, Hardware.all, :id, :model_with_brand_name %>
```

This will provide a dropdown menu containing all the brand names allowing you to pick the correct one for the hardware.

Comment: Hi Robin, you're right, my model's name is Hardware. I explain better. Says that I've another model,named Project and I use dropdown menu to associate "hardware" objects to a "project" object. You understand that including in a dropdown menu only "hardware.model" or "hardware.brand.name" is less useful because users can choose between [9300,5700,C636,..] in first case and between [HP,Lexmark,Cisco,Fortinet] in the latter case. That I'd like is if users can choose between these menu's elements: [HP 9300,Lexmark 5700,Cisco C636,..]   right?